# ASP.NET checkbox text issues

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox

I have been at this way too long, so I figure I would ask the question.
I have a bunch of checkboxes, they are all independent. I need them to appear next to each other witht the text appearing to the right-hand side. What i have is the code renders with the three checkboxes next to each other, followed on the same line by each respective text. What am I doing wrong, I can get the Front-end guy to change the markup, but I just don't know what do to.

here is my code:

```
<ul class="modal-options">
                <li>
                    <div class="label-by-checkbox">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="conPopcorn" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPopcorn" runat="server" Text="Popcorn"></asp:Label>

                        <asp:CheckBox ID="conNachos" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNachos" runat="server" Text="Nachos"></asp:Label> 

                         <asp:CheckBox ID="conPretzels" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPretzels" runat="server" Text="Pretzels"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: You probably need to use ASP:CheckBoxList, without some kind of formatting between each checkbox the content will flow inline. CheckBoxList has built in functions for table flow.

Comment: Are you using a css framework? Perhaps Bootstrap

Comment: thanks all, this will be handled in the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think you need use a table inside div, tr and td to draw your page
checkbox have a property Text so you no need a label to do it

Checkbox have the next property to align the text "TextAlign"

Comment: thank you... I tried a lot of that already. found out that this will be handled in the CSS, which I have no control over.